# Escape regex String in Java

Tags: java, regex

What is the proper way to escape this String `0x\w+:0x\w+[^][]*\K\[(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\]` to be used as a Java String variable.

*IntelliJ* escapes this automatically into (when pasted):

```
String pattern = "0x\\w+:0x\\w+[^][]*\\K\\[(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),\\s*(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\]";
```

However, this is causing compiler error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 18
```

Comment: That `[]` looks a bit weird. I'm fairly confident that's an error in your regex (it's also "*near index 18*"), but I'm intrigued to know if it's actually doing something.

Comment: Actually it's a regex for https://regex101.com/r/Yc81SJ

Comment: Look at the flavor that website is using. It is for php. Different languages have different flavors of regex.

Comment: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

Comment: fyi java doesn't support `\K`

Comment: What would be the replacement for `*\K\[`?

Comment: @xybrek But everything before `\K` in a `(?<=xxx)` positive look-behind. You also need to fix `[^][]`, because that don't work. Result: `"(?<=0x\\w+:0x\\w+[^\\[\\]]*)\\[(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),\\s*(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

```
\[\["0x\w+:0x\w+(.+?[\d+,\d+]]])
```

And here's the complete code (a bit long solution):

```
String arrayPatternString = "\\[\\[\"0x\\w+:0x\\w+(.+?[\\d+,\\d+]]])";
Pattern arrayPattern = Pattern.compile(arrayPatternString);
Matcher arrayMatcher = arrayPattern.matcher(responseBody);
while(arrayMatcher.find()) {
    String matched = arrayMatcher.group();
    String g = "(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),\\s*(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)";
    Pattern gPattern = Pattern.compile(g);
    Matcher gMatcher = gPattern.matcher(matched);
    while(gMatcher.find()) {
        String gMatched = gMatcher.group();
        String[] s = gMatched.split(",");
        Double lat = Double.valueOf(s[0]);
        Double lon = Double.valueOf(s[1]);
        System.out.println("Lat: " + lat);
        System.out.println("Lat: " + lon);
        map.put("latitude", lat);
        map.put("longitude", lon);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is better `\[\["0x\w+:0x\w+(.+?[\d+,\d+]])`

Answer (score 1):

`\K` is not valid regex. Not sure what you are trying to match with it. If you want a capitol K character, just put `K`

Comment: @xybrek Your check is for *PHP* flavour of the regular expressions. The Java flavour does not have `\K`, it only has `\k<index>`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html